# Как поменять иконку в окне User Account Control?

Tags: windows, windowsinstaller

Подскажите, возможно ли поменять иконку в окне "User Account Control", которая появилось в результате запуска удаления программы из списка "Uninstall or change program"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вот что я накопал.

Данные списка "Uninstall or change program" хранятся в реестре. Например, для FileZilla:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\FileZilla Client`

[image]

Там должно быть поле `UninstallString`, которое содержит команду командной строки на удаление программы.
Таким образом, если нужно чтобы в окне "User Account Control" была определённая иконка, то эта иконка должна быть в exe файле запускаемого этой командой. И соответственно этому процессу должны быть нужны админские права.